# Is there any merit in preceding jsx map function with array.length condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, jsx

In React JSX we can map over arrays to generate elements. A couple of common patterns when mapping over arrays in JSX, use conditional rendering like so:

`{ array.length ? array.map(...) : null }` or `{ array.length > 0 && array.map(...) }`

However, assuming your array is defined, why do developers check for the array length before mapping over it in JSX? Even if the array we want to map over is empty, it will simply not generate any elements and the app doesn't error/fall over.

Is there any merit in adding those conditions? Could it be that it is slightly more performant? Or is it simply down to personal coding style in the sense that it is believed to be reading better?

Comment: Might be useful if you want to do something other than `null` in that first one, but other than that, i agree you could just map over the empty array and nothing happens.

Comment: It will depend on your data array, for example, your data is coming through rest API and in jsx you will need to use extra good practice to check its validation either it presents some data or is undefined or null. If your data is static then you can ignore it. But its always a good practice for validation to your object, array in Javascript.

Comment: @UmeshVerma There's no problem with mapping over an empty array, so checking the length is useless.